# Splash screen editing Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

I'm currently running dual boot Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME. I updated my splash screen theme to one of plymouth's. About 3-7 seconds in to the loading, My splash screen seems to be getting interrupted by the following messages:

```
[    9.503563] systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and
[   23.132055] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

Here's my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="7"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub/zebra.png"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="1366x768"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

export GRUB_MENU_PICTURE="/home/qorka/Pictures/Plasma.png"
export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="white/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-magenta/black"


GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"

GRUB_FONT="/boot/grub/unicode.pf2"
```

Not exactly sure where the issue is or if this is fixable.

Comment: The first message is already way past the Grub/Plymouth stage. It says that there is something wrong with the Bluetooth service file, which is by default located in `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`. Your system complains that it is missing an `ExecStart=` statement, which I can confirm ought to be there. Please take a look at that file and tell us what you find.

Comment: I had commented out the ExecStart line to permanently disable bluetooth. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, that must be it. The command for that is  `sudo systemctl disable bluetooth`.

Comment: About the other error message, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110).

Comment: I don't have a USB plugged in, so that's pretty weird. I've been seeing that error for quite some time now too.

Comment: Interesting. What does `sudo lsusb` tell you about Bus 2, Device 5?

Comment: Looks like it's related to blueooth:

`Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth`

Comment: You may already have got rid of that message by disabling bluetooth. Although it's a bit weird that an internal card should be underpowered.

Comment: I had mentioned in another [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013087/grub-customizer-on-gnome-ubuntu-17-10-appearance-settings-not-being-recognized) that i'm noticing duplicate updates when I update my grub file. Is it possible this is all related? I know that's a pretty vague question.

Comment: I just rebooted, and no errors popped up, but the splash screen was still interrupted by a blank black screen...